# why D3DXCreateCylinder is not creating a cylinder?

Tags: c++, directx

> I am trying to make a ball trail.
>   `rBallPos` is correctly updating.
>   Following code is not working creating
>   a cylinder as ball's trail. How to
>   solve it?

```
LPD3DXMESH /*ID3DXMesh*/ ppMeshCylinder = NULL;
hr = D3DXCreateCylinder(g_d3d_device,0.1f,0.1f,0.1f,1,1,&ppMeshCylinder,0);
```

hr is FAILED here also hr != D3D_OK

```
D3DXMATRIX cylinder, cylinder2, cylinderRotate, cylinderTrans;
D3DXMatrixRotationX(&cylinderRotate, 1.5f);
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&cylinderTrans, rBallPos.fX, rBallPos.fY, rBallPos.fZ);
D3DXMatrixMultiply(&cylinder, &cylinderRotate, &cylinderTrans);
g_d3d_device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &cylinder);
ppMeshCylinder->DrawSubset(0);
```

Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>You need to pass in a pointer to `LPD3DXMESH`, so your mesh parameter should be `&ppMeshCylinder` instead of `ppMeshCylinder`. In fact, your compiler should have already warned you.</del>

**Update:** Try passing in a larger value for `Slices` and `Stacks`, say 5 or 10. It's not possible to create a cylindrical mesh with just 1 polygon.

Comment: m sorry for my mistake here .. it is &ppMeshCylinder. It is having runtime error. I updated it.

Comment: good point .. its now running without any runtime error and creating mesh. now I am not able to draw it ( I guess ) .. because the locations r ok. I am for now doing it and have to do it in Render() fn. what could possibly be wrong I m doing? Thanks for pointing 'Slice' and 'Stack'. ... And abt the no. value for these its not explained anywhere in MS-websites .. or I missed it. and with 1 slice and a stack a cylinder can be made, can't it (as in MAYA) ?

Comment: I am now able to draw it .. thanks a lot. However now I want to give color or texture or material to it. Just working on it. any pointer still will be helpful.

Comment: Just use `device->SetMaterial` and pass in a material structure with the properties you want. Or use `device->SetTexture` and pass in a texture (which you can create with `D3DXCreateTextureFromFile`).

Comment: These should work but it is not working, what could be the reason?

Comment: @casablanca: please have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644670/why-d3dxcreatecylinder-made-mesh-coloring-material-is-not-working