# why D3DXCreateCylinder made mesh coloring/material is not working?

Tags: c++, directx-9

This question is in continuation of "[why D3DXCreateCylinder is not creating a cylinder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583646/why-d3dxcreatecylinder-is-not-creating-a-cylinder)". I m able to draw the cylinder but it is only drawing it as [image: full white].

The code is as follows

```
void draw_Cylinder(void){

    D3DXMATRIX rot_matrix;
    D3DXMATRIX trans_matrix;
    D3DXMATRIX world_matrix;
    static float rot_triangle=0.0f;
    static float rot_triangle2=0.0f;


    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&rot_matrix,rot_triangle);  //Rotate the cylinder
    D3DXMatrixRotationX(&rot_matrix,rot_triangle2);  //Rotate the cylinder
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&trans_matrix,2.0f,0,20.0f); //Shift it 2 units to the left
    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&world_matrix,&rot_matrix,&trans_matrix);



    D3DMATERIAL9  material;// = new D3DMATERIAL9();



    ZeroMemory( &material, sizeof(D3DMATERIAL9) );

    // Set the RGBA for diffuse reflection.
    material.Diffuse.r = 0.5f;
    material.Diffuse.g = 0.0f;
    material.Diffuse.b = 0.5f;
    material.Diffuse.a = 1.0f;

    // Set the RGBA for ambient reflection.
    material.Ambient.r = 0.5f;
    material.Ambient.g = 0.0f;
    material.Ambient.b = 0.5f;
    material.Ambient.a = 1.0f;

    // Set the color and sharpness of specular highlights.
    material.Specular.r = 1.0f;
    material.Specular.g = 1.0f;
    material.Specular.b = 1.0f;
    material.Specular.a = 1.0f;
    material.Power = 2.0f;

    // Set the RGBA for emissive color.
    material.Emissive.r = 0.0f;
    material.Emissive.g = 0.0f;
    material.Emissive.b = 0.0f;
    material.Emissive.a = 0.0f;


    g_d3d_device->SetMaterial(&material);

    g_d3d_device->SetTexture(0,NULL);

    g_d3d_device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD,&world_matrix);
    m_ppMeshCylinder->DrawSubset(0);
    ////Render from our Vertex Buffer
    //g_d3d_device->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, //PrimitiveType
    //                            0,                  //StartVertex
    //                            g_pyramid_count);   //PrimitiveCount

    rot_triangle+=0.0007f;
    if(rot_triangle > D3DX_PI*2)
    {  
        rot_triangle-=D3DX_PI*2;
    }

    rot_triangle2+=0.0007f;
    if(rot_triangle2 > D3DX_PI*2)
    {  
        rot_triangle2-=D3DX_PI*2;
    }
}
```

or download the project.
I have attracted my codes here "[project code](https://sites.google.com/site/dedicated2robotics/notaspartofthesite/3d_objects.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)"
I want to draw it having 3D shades what generally any 3D mesh has if rendered by default.
I am not nicely aware of materials. Or is it the problem with graphics card (I just thought :D  ).

In addition where can I get information and samples abt `SetRenderState`

Comment: Have you also set up a light source before? If not, you need to do that.

Comment: Fine, it working here in the same project after I added a light .. but not in the main project (another separate project). I tried it vertex way as follows For it light is not required. It really has gone tough for me.  'pTempEarthMesh->CloneMeshFVF( 0, D3DFVF_MY_VERTEX, g_pd3dDevice, &g_pEarthMesh ); CUSTOMVERTEX *pVertices = NULL; pTempVertexBuffer->Lock( 0, 0, (void**)&pVertices, 0 ); {for( int i = 0; i < nNumVerts; ++i )pVertices[i].diffuse = D3DCOLOR_COLORVALUE( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 );'

Comment: It worked for the project I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
g_d3d_device->SetRenderState( D3DRS_DIFFUSEMATERIALSOURCE, D3DMCS_MATERIAL );
```

At the moment it is defaulting to using "Color 1" which is the first of the 2 possible vertex colours.

Comment: Lighting has done the required. please also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700001/how-to-give-a-mesh-vertex-like-self-lighitng