# How to give a mesh, vertex like self lighitng?

Tags: c++, directx, vertex, level-of-detail, id3dxmesh

How we can give any complex mesh, vertex like self lighting.
I tried increasing light ambient, material ambient, but as soon as it goes far it starts disappearing. I want that to be visible at whatever distance it is at.
I have tried getting vertex from a cylinder then putting color in it, works fine for colors but fails at distance.

[have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583646/why-d3dxcreatecylinder-is-not-creating-a-cylinder)
and [have a look at this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644670/why-d3dxcreatecylinder-made-mesh-coloring-material-is-not-working)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really follow what your question is. Are you attempting to create a glow effect for your mesh? Do you want your mesh to behave like a light source? If you could more clearly explain what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to help.
Sorry if I misunderstood. :)

Comment: @BKevelham: In DirecX light given to any vertex does not require light, to view it, but for mesh it is required. I want the same should be applied to mesh. and yeah if glow can be given wud be an add-on here. :D

Comment: Do you want to apply light only to some vertices?

Comment: @Tiago: no, I don't want to deal with the world lighting at all. just like when we do it with vertexBuffer made mesh or strip.